# How Do I Get Secure Image URLs in Magento

Tags: ssl, https, secure

I ınstalled a Comodo Positive SSL about 3 hours ago.
And i made the changes in admin panel for using https.

But ı have that problem when i changed to https, all images, css and js stop working. And when i see the source of page all these images and css are still comes from http links. 
For short front end layout is not shown well. I looked people if they had same problem before, like me but only found irrelevant stuff and basic things to made only pull visitors. This is bad really.

How can i do that?
Site is solempet.com

Comment: did you clear the cache and are you sure the media URLs in the backend are set to secure?

Answer (score 3):

If you want you site to always use https then you simply need to change the secure and the unsecured URL's to use https via the admin configuration section.

> System->Configuration->Web->Secure/Insecure

This will then make sure that any URL that Magento generates will be over https. After making this change you will probably need to re-index and clear your cache.

Comment: this is what I did, and it worked for me. Running a static content deploy would also help regenerate some of those files in https.